# hi there, would anyone mind explaining what this code means?

Tags: c++

Essentially, my friend wrote this code and did what i had done in these three lines whereas mine was nearly a page, i don't understand what it means could someone help please.

```
msg[i] = toupper(msg[i]);
msg[i] = ((msg[i] - 'A')+rotation)%26;
printf("%c", calpha[msg[i]]);
```

Comment: "my friend wrote this code" -  ask your friend....? Otherwise. break it down and show your attempt

Comment: asleep and my work is due tomorrow morning

Comment: its the middle line that confuses me i just dont understand it at all

Comment: hint: what is the value of 'A'? (it's char literal)

Comment: im unsure as to what a char literal is even after looking it up

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ caesar cipher".  You may end up with some posts to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

```
// convert a - z character to upper case A - Z
msg[i] = toupper(msg[i]);

// A - Z values are 65 - 90. Subtract from uppercase character 65 (which is A)
// which moves it to 0 - 25 range. Add some shift value to it (rotation)
// %26 brings it back to 0 - 25 range.
msg[i] = ((msg[i] - 'A')+rotation)%26;

// print calpha value for given index (our 0 - 25 result)
printf("%c", calpha[msg[i]]);
```